# ¿Cómo desarrollar un método que imprima un mensaje utilizando el paradigma de Orientado a objetos en C++?

Tags: c++, poo, método, print, imprimir

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer que un método pueda imprimir un mensaje con parametros? Puse el using namespace std; y el #include  en Punto.cpp, pero me marca error en la parte de cout, a pesar que invoco el namespace std y el #include

Imprimiendo el código lo único que me marca error es en el cout, y es porque dice que no está definido, ¿acaso se necesita utilizar otra librería para ello?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta importando

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias <3
De verdad me sirvió muy bien!!!

Comment: @Legend si bien tu aporte puede solucionar el problema, el solo responder con código se considera a de baja calidad, lee [answer]